# Calculating position in an array with screen coordinates for an isometric game

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates, isometric

I'm making a very basic Isometric game in java using [this](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers/) site, only the method it uses to convert screen coordinates to a position in an array doesn't work.

this is what I use to convert screen coordinates to array position:

```
public void GetMouseInArray(){
    int[] pos = new int[2];

    pos[0] = window.getMousePosition().x;
    pos[1] = window.getMousePosition().

    pos = CalcCarPos(pos);

    int[] temppos = new int[2];
    temppos[0] = (int) Math.floor(pos[0]/80);
    temppos[1] = (int) Math.floor(pos[1]/80);
    pos = temppos;
}
```

And this is the CalcCarPos function:

```
private int[] CalcCarPos(int[] pos){
    int[] temppos = new int[2];
    temppos[0] = (2*pos[1]+pos[0])/2;
    temppos[1] = (2*pos[1]-pos[0])/2;
    return temppos;
}
```

I'm using almost the same code for drawing the array on screen and my tiles are 80x80 pixels. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: would recommend using a [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) to store coordinants as it is slightly cleaner than `int[]`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, I changed all ints to Point. I know it doesn't work because I change the screen title to the converted position.

Comment: "change the screen title" so you've made a window and are testing the code in it? code you please also include the code you are testing it with?

Answer (score 0):

```
temppos[0] = (2*pos[1]+pos[0])/2;
temppos[1] = (2*pos[1]-pos[0])/2;
```

Is this what you want? What this is saying is multiply pos[1] by 2, add pos[0] to that result then devide it by 2. Or do you want multiply the sum of pos[1] and pos[0] by 2?

```
temppos[0] = (2*(pos[1]+pos[0]))/2;
temppos[1] = (2*(pos[1]-pos[0]))/2;
```

Comment: lets say I've selected X: 165, Y: 165. You want to return the array position 1,1? Correct.